# Text replacements removes <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my div:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
     <a href="/admin/">Domov</a>
     &rsaquo; <a href="/admin/authtoken/">Tokenová autorizácia</a>
     &rsaquo; Tokens
</div>
```

I need to replace text “Tokens” with “Tokeny”
So I am using this jQuery code:

```
$(".breadcrumbs").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Tokens", "Tokeny");
});
```

Text is replaced, but I am loosing all “a href” tags.
Result content of breadcrumbs div is:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
     Domov
     &rsaquo;Tokenová autorizácia
     &rsaquo; Tokeny
</div>
```

How can I preserve "a href" links when I am replacing the text?

Comment: This is due to your code is fetching out just the `text` but the `html`, it should be assigning and fetching both `html`, so replace js `.text` to `.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `html()` instead of `text()` in order to keep your html tags:

```
let replaced = $(".breadcrumbs").html().replace("Tokens", "Tokeny");
$(".breadcrumbs").html(replaced);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using `text()`, which removes the HTML. Use `html()` instead. You can also make the code more succinct by providing a function to the method which accepts the current HTML as an argument, which you can then amend and return. Try this:

```js
$(".breadcrumbs").html((i, html) => html.replace("Tokens", "Tokeny"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
     <a href="/admin/">Domov</a>
     &rsaquo; <a href="/admin/authtoken/">Tokenová autorizácia</a>
     &rsaquo; Tokens
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".breadcrumbs").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace("Tokens", "Tokeny");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
     <a href="/admin/">Domov</a>
     &rsaquo; <a href="/admin/authtoken/">Tokenová autorizácia</a>
     &rsaquo; Tokens
</div>
```